# Iteración en bucle for decremental

Tags: c#

Tengo un duda con el comportamiento de un bucle FOR decremental. Cuando llega a 0 no entra. Me explico con el código...

```
int z = 10;

            for (int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
            { 
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    z = 100;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Si os fijáis, se supone que cuando `i==1` el FOR se cumple, y lo último que debe hacer es decrementar hasta el valor `i==0`, de manera que la última vuelta del bucle i debería valer 0 y entrar en el IF.
Lo que realmente pasa (comprobando depurando línea a línea en el VisualStudio) es que el código realmente hace la decrementación de i (reduciéndola a valor 0), después comprueba si es mayor que 0, y como no lo es no entra en el FOR, ni, como consecuencia, en el IF.

He consultado la referencia de Microsoft respecto a FOR (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) y dice que

> la sección iterador define lo que sucede después de cada iteración del
>   cuerpo del bucle

Total, que yo que entendía que el bucle FOR tenía tres secciones (inicializador, condición e iterador), y que se ejecutaban en ese orden... O alguien me lo explica, o estoy más perdido que nadie; es como si la lectura secuencial del código fuera hacia atrás.

Comment: La i=0 esta fuera del for. No esta incluida. Debes poner i => 0

Comment: Sí, pero no entiendo por qué está fuera del FOR. Si yo voy leyendo paso a paso las secciones del bucle FOR, en la última vuelta, cuando empiezo a leer...

i==1
Entro en el FOR
i es mayor que 0
por tanto, tiene que restar 1 a i
por lo que i==0
y entraría en el IF

Comment: Lo puedes entender como un for (true), siempre y que la condición sea true entrará dentro. Antes de entrar a la nueva iteracion del for, decremento en 1 el valor. Por lo que cuando decremento la i, y esta llega a 0, la condición true no se mantiene.

Comment: la condición del ciclo dice que solo se ejecute si `i > 0`, de esta forma cuando `ì`es `0` no se cumple y por ende no se ejecuta, la condición debe ser `i >= 0`.

Comment: Entonces primero decrementa y luego comprueba. Eso es lo que he visto al depurar en el Visual, pero realmente eso es ir para atrás en la lectura del código, porque la comparación está escrita antes de la sección de iteración.

Esto es lo que me ha sorprendido

Comment: Sí @isaac, pero cuando i llega a ser 0 ya debería haber entrado en el FOR, y por tanto, el siguiente paso secuencial es ir al IF. Parece como que se vuelve a salir e intenta volver a entrar al FOR (valiendo ya 0) antes de ir al IF; por eso, no consigue entrar la última vez

Comment: No, cuando `i` se decrementa a `0`, no entra en el ciclo, hasta ahí solo se ha decrementado, la siguiente fase del `for` es validar si la condición se cumple, es decir la parte del medio `i > 0`, si esto se cumple (es `true`), ingresa a ejecutar el bloque del `for`, qué como menciona la primera instrucción es el `if(i == 0)`, pero `i > 0`con `i` igual a `0` no da `true` da `false` y por eso no se ejecuta el bloque del `if`, la condición de ejecución debe ser `i >= 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tu dices es totalmente cierto.

El bucle FOR consta de 3 partes `for (inicializador, condición, iterador)`
El for se ejecuta según esta escrito.

Como habrás comprobado en la primera inicialización, `i` vale `20`. No es hasta que acaba de hacer todas las instrucciones, que se va a evaluar el `iterador`. No tendría sentido nada más entrar ejecutar el `iterador`.

Por lo que para el último caso, y donde tienes la problemática:

El valor de `i` vale `1`, evalúa la `condición` y como es `true` entra dentro del `for` y ejecuta todas las instrucciones. Una vez acaba el, decrementa el valor de `i` a `0`.

Ahora vuelve a evaluar la condición `i` como `i > 0` es false, finaliza el `for`.

Comment: Muchas gracias David_helo. Duda resuelta

Dejo un vídeo donde Juan, de PildorasInformáticas, lo explica perfectamente. He colocado el temporizador del vídeo justo donde empieza la explicación.
https://youtu.be/Cx0UW5PQJG0?t=327

Answer (score 0):

tu problema esta en esta parte

```
    for (int i = 20; --> i > 0 <--; i--)
```

la `i` se disminuye hasta llegar solo hasta 1. si deseas que llegue hasta el 0 deberia ser asi

```
 for (int i = 20;  i >= 0 ; i--)
```

de esta forma ya entraria a la condición del if